# How to efficiently find all stored subsets of a set? (association rule lookup)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, data-mining

I have been experimenting with [association rule learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) lately, generating rules from a vast database of transactions. I'd like to use these rules to make recommendations in real time.

There is lots of literature available on how to *generate* the rules, but I can't seem to find any information on how people actually utilize these rules in a real time fashion, and bruteforce is excruciatingly slow.

So the question is:
I have thousands and thousands of sets R (the rule antecedents), and I want to get all sets (from R) that are proper subsets of some provided set X. How can I do this most efficiently?

(Only lookup has to be fast, building the datastructure does not)

Additional information:

- R contains ~20000 sets (right now, should support more).
- The sets in R usually have a cardinality of less than 10.
- X usually has a cardinality of around 30, but can be as big as 1000 (rare).
- All sets discussed contain integers (database IDs) from 0 to around 30000 (at the moment).

Comment: I have a few questions. How large do you expect X to be? Also, do you know all possible values of X that could be input, and is that number based on the size of R?

Comment: Good questions @JaysonBoubin, I'll update the question.

Comment: Size of X has no relation to size of R, by the way.

Comment: You say that X usually has a size of 30 but can be as big as 1000. Do you know all of the possible values X can be? If so, how large is it?

Comment: Well, X is a list of product IDs that a user has in his cart, and the lookup is used to find _other_ products the user might want to buy based on the association rules. There is no limit to how many products a user can have in his cart, but no examples in my database have over 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Don't over-automate.

It is usually a bad idea to try to automatically use the output of any *unsupervised* method. Rather, the output *needs* to be analyzed and checked by a human. There are too many patterns that are "correct" but without any value to the business, or any novelty. They may simply reflect how e.g. current product recommendations work, or how the store is currently arranged. For example, mathematically it may appear to be best to suggest tomato sauce to people who buy pasta. And while indeed this is a common association, you probably sell 0 additional tomato sauce with this recommendation, because everybody is well aware that pasta+tomato tastes well, no need to tell them.

Instead, allow the expert to browse through the rules, find those that are *unexpected* and then plan a proper A/B test to verify if this really works.

Comment: While sound advice in general, this does not answer the question. Let's assume (without loss of generality) that the rules have been curated by an expert -- we still might have too many rules to use bruteforce for querying.

Comment: I don't think you have a problem to match millions of rules with a simple tree matcher. Most likely, you are just approaching it badly, by trying to compute all sets, rather than matching.